# Asynchronous Action WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, asynchronous, woocommerce

When an order has the status changed I need to send a POST to a specific API.

So, I did something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_async_test_check', 'test_function' );

function test_function($order_id) {
  $api = new Custom_Api();
  $result = $api->check($order_id);
  update_post_meta( $order_id, "api_result", $result );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'test_order_status_changed' ) ) {
  function test_order_status_changed( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status ) {
    if( $new_status == "processing" ) {
      wp_schedule_single_event( 1, 'wp_async_test_check', [ $order_id ] );
    }
  }

  add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'test_order_status_changed', 10, 3 );
}
```

What is the problem? When executing this line "`$result = $api->check($order_id);`" takes about 40 seconds to end the API request, so, the execution continues without saving the correct data in the post meta in this line "`update_post_meta( $order_id, "api_result", $result );`". I need to get the API request result to save.

I already tried to use the `as_enqueue_async_action` method, but I'm not able to call this inside the test_order_status_changed function. I tried:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'test_order_status_changed' ) ) {
  function test_order_status_changed( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status ) {
    if( $new_status == "processing" ) {
      add_action( 'init', function() {
        add_action( 'test_order_status_changed_asap', 'test_order_status_changed_asap', $order_id );
        as_enqueue_async_action( 'test_order_status_changed_asap' );
      } );
    }
  }

  add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'test_order_status_changed', 10, 3 );

  function test_order_status_changed_asap( $order_id ) {
    $api = new Custom_Api();
    $result = $api->check($order_id);
    update_post_meta( $order_id, "api_result", $result );
  }
}
```

The "`test_order_status_changed_asap`" is not being called. I tested calling the add_action with the "init" parameter without being inside a function and it works, but I need to call the asap method inside the test_order_status_changed method.

WordPress Version: 5.9 / WooCommerce Version: 6.4 / PHP Version: 7.3

Comment: Does your `Custom_Api` accept some sort of a callback or does it return some sort of a `Promise`?

Comment: @Jared unfortunately not and I'm sending/requesting the data from API using the wp_remote_post method.

Comment: If the `check` method is async, what does it even return?

Comment: @Jared the `check` is not async what makes it async is the `wp_schedule_single_event` method.

Comment: I'm not sure why do you even need pseudo-async WP functions. You could just get pending orders and run your `check` for them (or one of them) on every request (or every nth request).

Comment: @Jared because if I execute the `check` without the async wp function it reaches the timeout and WordPress doesn't wait for the execution. And that API request happens after the user makes an order and I think it is not a good idea to make the user waits about 40 seconds (API request). Could you give me some example of how I can do that in an async way and get the result to save the API response as a post meta?

Comment: PHP is not asynchronous out of the box, so things WP calls 'async' are actually delayed sync. If `check` needs 40 seconds to run, it will require these 40 secs later. So if you need to put that task into real background, it gotta be a cron job or some daemonized script run via `shell_exec`.

Comment: @Jared Yes! I was trying to execute even delayed sync way. Now I fixed the problem, my POST request was limited with a 10 seconds timeout. And it was causing all the trouble. Thank you for your help and patience.